# Can't save file on iOS 14.1

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsfilemanager

I've killed a few days trying to save a file and list it in a home directory.

First I retrieve a home directory URL.
I tried two options:

```
docDir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
docDir = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
```

In any way when running on simulator or my iPhone it results in just `file:///`
Well, maybe that's ok for sandboxed iOS app...

After that I prepare a file URL. I tried two ways:

```
let file = docDir.appendingPathComponent("myfile.tmp")
let file = URL(fileURLWithPath: "myfile.tmp")
print(file.absoluteURL)
```

Here I get `file:///myfile.tmp` (in both variants)

Finally I try to create file

```
        do {
            try  Data(count: 0).write(to: file2)
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed to create file: '\(file)' because of: \(error)")
        }
```

And here is what I get

**On simulator:**

> Failed to create file: './myfile.tmp -- file:///' because of: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=642 "You can’t save the file
> “myfile.tmp” because the volume “AirHD — данные” is read only."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/myfile.tmp, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000dea1f0
> {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=30 "Read-only file system"}}

**On iPhone:**

> Failed to create file: './myfile.tmp -- file:///' because of: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save
> the file “myfile.tmp” in the folder “System”."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/myfile.tmp, NSUnderlyingError=0x281725a40 {Error
> Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

But why in the folder “System” ??
It should have been my Documents folder!

UPD: setting  keys `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` in `Info.plist` file did not help also.

Comment: `URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())` is wrong

Comment: try `let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")` and then `try Data([97,98,99]).write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)`. This will create a text file with an abc string content

Comment: Thank you! Your comment did help me to find the problem!

Answer (score 0):

After more enquiries I found the problem!
It was because I wrapped my `docDir` into a `@State` modifier
Actually it was

```
@State var docDir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

And for some reason this modifier turned actual URL to `file:///`

Comment: just make sure when initializing an URL if your string has the `file://` prefix to use the `URL(string:)` initializer otherwise use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`. Also when getting a string from url `absoluteString` would include the scheme `file://` while `path` would not.